# "carthage update --platform iOS" gets stuck at "Fetching Decodable"

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, carthage

My team is using [Decodable](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Decodable) library in application with the help of **carthage**. The command `carthage update --platform iOS` is properly downloading the [Decodable](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Decodable) on my colleague mac machine. But on my mac machine it's just stucks with the message `*** Fetching Decodable` all the time. I am trying it since 2 days. for better understanding please see the bellow attached screenshot of terminal

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens when Carthage can't find compatible version of your dependency. Try specifying a version of the library in your `Cartfile`

Comment: the Cartfile Decodable library version is same as the stable version of Decodable.

Comment: is the schemes option set to shared?